# IntelliJ 2019.3 Why can't I see the 'NEXT' button? What is the cause?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: This is the image]

File > New > Module From Existing Sources > maven module choose

You will see a 'FINISH' button instead of a 'NEXT' button. What is the cause?

This is IntelliJ Version is 2019.3

I need to see the 'NEXT' button so I can go through the detailed settings in the next step.

why different?

In 2019.2 version, you will see the 'NEXT' button.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-223880#focus=streamItem-27-3723862.0-0) from the responsible developer:

> The dialog was removed to minimize the friction when opening the Maven/Gradle projects in the IDE, please see [IDEA-223880](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-223880) and [IDEA-191523](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-191523) for details.

Maven settings can be changed in Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Importing section after importing the project.

Comment: After all, do you not see the 'NEXT' button in 2019.3 version?

Comment: Yes, it's by design.